# NodeJS Module.Exports Object Prototype Problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, function-prototypes

I'm just barely getting into NodeJS a bit and have hit a snag trying to create a (VERY)basic MVC implementation for it.

It comes down to the following. I have a main object for a Controller that I'm trying to create a prototype for; The code as follows:

```
var Controller = function(obj) {

    this.request = null;
    this.response = null;
    this.params = null;
    this.layout = 'default';    

}

Controller.prototype = new function() {

    this.processAction = function(action) {
        console.log("Processing Action.");
    }

}

module.exports = new Controller();
```

I've stripped most of the values / functions out for this problem as they don't really relate. Basically from my understanding using the module.exports will export the object to a variable using the require() function. I have the following in my dispatcher:

```
var Controller = require('./Controller.js');
```

The problem is whenever I printout the variable Controller I get the first part of the object but the prototype has not been included. See the following printout:

```
{ request: null,
  response: null,
  params: null,
  layout: 'default' }
```

Thus calling the prototype function Controller.processAction() results in a no method error. Am I declaring this prototype wrong or is there something I'm missing related to NodeJS?

[EDIT]

I've also tried the following style for adding a prototype to no avail.

```
Controller.prototype = {
    'processAction' : function(action) {
        console.log("Processing Action");
    }
}
```

[EDIT 2]

Nevermind, the above worked console.log doesn't report the additional functionality in the prototype, interesting.

Comment: Your ___exact___ code works fine.  Have you actually tried calling `.processAction()` or are you just assuming that since it doesn't show up in a log it doesn't exist?  Some versions of node don't properly iterate through `__proto__`

Comment: You're absolutely right. It didn't show up in the log so I assumed it wasn't there. Thanks for the help.

Comment: In case you don't know `new function()` returns an object not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Controller.prototype = {
    processAction : function(){
        // code
    },

    anotherMethod : function(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
Controller.prototype = {
    processAction : function(action) {
        console.log("Processing Action.");
    }
}
```